# CentOS instance on Amazon Lightsail "bricked" out of the blue, how to resolve?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

My CentOS 7 instance on Amazon Lightsail (AWS) will suddenly no longer respond to SSH.  Even the "Connect Using SSH" button on the Lightsail site shows me only a blank black screen.

I have rebooted, stopped / started, no change.

Amazon offers zero support for a Lightsail account, how do I resolve this without upgrading for support?

Comment: Connect via VNC console if they provide such.

Comment: @Hardoman sadly, they don't seem to have that option